# Python SimpleGui multiple windows

Tags: python, pysimplegui

So basically i am using SimpleGUI and am able to create multiple windows, even with same content without errors.
Now i just cannot get the events happening in the other windows that were created.

Is there any solution to create multiple windows and catch their events?

Comment: https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/#recipe-multiple-windows-read_all_windows

Answer (score 1):

For PySimpleGUI, instead of `window.read`, call `sg.read_all_windows` in event loop for multi-windows.

###### window, event, values = read_all_windows(timeout=None, timeout_key=TIMEOUT_KEY)

Reads all windows that are "active" when the call is made. "Active" means that it's been finalized or read.
If a window has not been finalized then it will not be considered an "active window"

If any of the active windows returns a value then the window and its event and values are returned.

If no windows are open, then the value (None, WIN_CLOSED, None) will be returned
Since WIN_CLOSED is None, it means (None, None, None) is what's returned when no windows remain opened

Comment: Worked out perfectly for me thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use event viewer to navigate through:

- Open Event Viewer by clicking the Start button
- Click Control Panel
- Click System and Security
- Click Administrative Tools
- Click Event Viewer

Comment: This is a coding question about PySimpleGUI, so it should be about PySimpleGUI code. If your method works, you will still have to do on other Windows (which is bad idea) + he/she may not use Windows.